# Reorder character based on the order of another character in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a character with two Hex color codes:

```
[1] "#F9CF7B" "#C5D4E1"
```

I also have a dataframe, where the levels of a factor variable are like this:

```
[1] "Treated" "Placebo"
```

These levels may change it's order (this is a shinyApp, but that's not the main point of the question)
So sometimes I will have the factors ordered like this `[1] "Treated" "Placebo"`, and other times like this,
`[1] "Placebo" "Treated"`. What I want is my hex color code character to change it's order accordingly.

So, I would have something like.

`[1] "Treated" "Placebo"` -> `[1] "#F9CF7B" "#C5D4E1"`

And

`[1] "Placebo" "Treated"` -> `[1] "#C5D4E1" "#F9CF7B"`

I was thinking of creating a dataframe with this two factors, then reordening the whole dataframe based on the levels of the factor, and extracting the reordered hex codes.

However, I would like to know if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to pass a named vector to match the `levels` of the `factor`

```
nm1 <- setNames(c("#F9CF7B", "#C5D4E1"), c("Treated", "Placebo"))
v1 <- factor(sample(rep(c("Treated", "Placebo"), 3)))
nm1[levels(v1)]
 Placebo   Treated 
"#C5D4E1" "#F9CF7B"
```